# Trying to call python script from VBA

Tags: python, excel, vba

I need to call a python script from an Excel macro using VBA. I am getting an error message "method run of object iwshshell3 failed" and cannot figure out why.

I have tried editing the paths, redownloading Spyder, etc.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
  Dim objShell As Object
  Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
  Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  PythonExe = "C:\Users\Frydman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe"
  PythonScript = "C:\Users\Frydman\.spyder-py3\temp.py"
  objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
End Sub
```

This is my VBA code that isn't working

I am getting the error message:

> "method run of object iwshshell3 failed".

I expect my python code to run after i call my macro which this VBA code is stored in.

Comment: Try to pass the path to the script file with the quotes

Comment: At least leave a space between those two paths

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example calling python in VB, from the documentation pages of http://docs.xlwings.org/en/v0.6.4/index.html

```
Sub MyMacro()
    RunPython ("import mymodule; mymodule.rand_numbers()")
End Sub
```

Then in your python script

```
import numpy as np
from xlwings import Workbook, Range

def rand_numbers():
    """ produces std. normally distributed random numbers with shape (n,n)"""
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    n = int(Range('Sheet1', 'B1').value)  # Write desired dimensions into Cell B1
    rand_num = np.random.randn(n, n)
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = rand_num
```